# Max size of uploaded files to IIs 6 server

Tags: iis, asp-classic, filesize

I have a few .asp pages which are used for visitors to upload files to my webserver.

They have worked perfectly for years on IIS5/Windows 2000 adv. server.

Now i've changed to IIS6/Server 20003. I after that users can only upload files no bigger than about 120 Kb.

My question is, how/where to increase to a max filesize of say, 10 Mb ?

Comment: See this link:  http://forums.eukhost.com/f15/increase-file-upload-size-asp-asp-net-9378/

Answer (score 3):

I found the (easy) solution at http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp